# Add username as prefix in route URI in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I am building an application where users are registered and want to be redirected to their individual dashboard like this .

`http://localhost/project/{username}/dashboard,`

Now, its happening like

`localhost/project/vendors/dashboard` (here all users are accessing same URL)

but I want to make it like :

`http://localhost/project/{username1}/dashboard,  http://localhost/project/{username2}/dashboard`

Googled lot but none of them are explained well and working.

**Please assist with complete flow.**

1. I want to declare the value of {username} globally and use it in route as prefix.
2. I dont want to use it before each name route. will use it as prefix and group with all `vendors` routes

I have made this, and its working as

`localhost/project/vendors/dashboard`

```
Route::prefix('vendors')->group(function () { Route::middleware(['auth:vendor'])->group(function () { Route::get('/dashboard', [VendorController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('vendor.dashboard'); });
});
```

Comment: Can you please show your controller? In the function you have to specify that you're pulling the User model.

Comment: you can use a route parameter as a prefix ... `prefix('vendors/{user}'...`

Comment: Thanks, Can you please write with complete guide ? how to declare the {username} globally and use it as prefix in route ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify route parameters in brackets like so `{parameter}`, change your code into this.

```
Route::get('project/{username}/dashboard', [UserDashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])
    ->name('user.dashboard');
```

In your controller you could access it like this.

```
class UserDashboardController
{
    public function dashboard(string $username)
    {
        User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();

        // something else
    }
}
```

Seems like in your routes your are mixing vendor prefix logic in with something that in your specifications of what your urls should look like does not match. Which i think is making up some of the confusion on this case.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to declare the value of {username} globally and use it as prefix in route. How to achieve this ?

Comment: you can also use route parameters as a prefix?

Comment: Can you please guide me with full code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: the other answer did it already, and you did not think it was right. Tbh. i do not think actually what you mean by globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route prefix like this

```
Route::prefix('{username}')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('user.dashboard');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank, but how to declare the {username} globally and use it as prefix ?

Comment: As per your question, If you want to access URL like this `http://localhost/project/{username1}/dashboard` their will work